# Cafe, library ambience noise generator

Tags: web-apps, audio, productivity, relaxation, noise-generator

I've been looking into the benefits of white/ambient noise on studying lately, and I think it's best to put on some cafe, busy library, study place ambient noise (with people talking in the background). I've been looking for audio tracks of this kind. So far I've found some that are simply "sound effects", which last < 1 minute. But what I really want is an audio track that plays for several hours with no looping.

I've searched (on YouTube, Soundcloud, Google, and Bing) for terms like "ambient noise", "ambient chatter", "background chatter", "background murmur", "background conversation noise", "study ambience", "ambient conversation", and the like. But most samples are < 1 minute and some of the longer samples either are NOT conversations or are cleverly disguised loops. But I haven't found anything like that.

Is there a web app that has a collection of ambient background noise that I described?

Comment: +1 interesting! Any answer about an app that dynamically generate such noise would be on-topic here. Any answer about very long sound files would probably be off-topic because it is not software, but don't worry there is a place for that: As a personal experiment I copied your question to http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/1945/cafe-library-ambience-noise-database I hope you don't mind! Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best I could come up with is [Babble Noise Generator](http://mynoise.net/NoiseMachines/babbleNoiseGenerator.php). You can adjust the various sliders to customise the background conversation and even have it randomly and slowly change over time by using the 'Animate!' button.

[image: Babble Screenshot]

They also have an app available for iOS, an .mp3 download feature, and over on their main page ([MyNoise.net](http://mynoise.net/noiseMachines.php)), they have a much wider range of random/white noise generators.