# Live streaming background noise

Tags: web-apps, audio, hosted, relaxation, noise-generator

I use background noise sites such as [noisli.com](http://www.noisli.com/), [raining.fm](http://raining.fm/), [coding.fm](http://coding.fm/). However, after using it for a long time, I noticed they are looped (I always knew they are looped, but have just recently *noticed* it).

Are there any web apps where the background noise is streamed live, or changes frequently enough for a long-term user to not notice the repetition?

This is similar to [this question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/3507/1460), but that question looks for longer tracks, whereas I am looking for **different**, unlooped, (live) tracks. (Since I even noticed the longer tracks looping,)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only found one website offering this so far: http://www.livenaturesongs.com/

I am also looking for something more than just nature sounds, like sounds from a cafe or air conditioners etc. but that might involve privacy issues regarding people being recorded. I guess that's why something like that isn't out there (yet)...

Comment: Thanks! That's a great site. I will accept your answer for now, until something better comes along!